# Issue in uploading artifacts to Nexus via Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins-pipeline, devops, nexus

I'm uploading artifacts to Nexus using Jenkinsfile. I'm getting below mentioned error. Also, adding Jenkinsfile below. Please help!

**ERROR**

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: simpleapp for class: groovy.lang.Binding
    at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:270)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$7.call(Checker.java:353)
```

**Jenkinsfile**

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    tools {
        maven 'maven3'
    }
    options {
        buildDiscarder logRotator(daysToKeepStr: '5', numToKeepStr: '7')
    }
    stages{
        stage('Build'){
            steps{
                 bat script: 'mvn clean package'
                 archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'target/*.war', onlyIfSuccessful: true
            }
        }
        stage('Upload War To Nexus'){
            steps{
                script{


                    nexusArtifactUploader artifacts: [
                        [
                            artifactId: 'simple-app', 
                            classifier: '', 
                            file: "target/simple-app-1.0.0.war", 
                            type: 'war'
                        ]
                    ], 
                    credentialsId: 'nexus3', 
                    groupId: 'in.javahome', 
                    nexusUrl: 'http://localhost:8081/', 
                    nexusVersion: 'nexus3', 
                    protocol: 'http', 
                    repository: simpleapp-release, 
                    version: '1.0.0'
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `repository` of `nexusArtifactUploader` is [Type: `String`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/nexus-artifact-uploader/). What if you write`repository: 'simpleapp-release'`?

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot the single quotes around the repository name